# Performance Impact of Constant Login / Logout SQL On High Latency Connection

Tags: sql-server

I'm reviewing the performance of a .NET application that sends 1,000s of consecutive select statements to a Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Instance. Ping time to server from client is 70 ms or higher across a WAN.

The client application is using Ole DB to connect to the SQL database.

Almost every single query SQL Profiler shows this pattern

- Audit:Login
- SQL:BatchStarting (Single SELECT statement)
- SQL:BatchCompleted
- Audit:Logout
- RPC:Completed - exec sp_reset_connection

This repeats thousands of times. Is it possible the application could be re-coded to avoid constant login / logout, saving expensive network calls

Or is it expected to see this information for every query.

Answer (score 2):

If [Audit:Login EventSubclass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-login-event-class?view=sql-server-2017)=2, then this is expected, and shouldn't be an issue.  The client is just reusing a connection from a connection pool and "resetting" the connection to clear any impersonations, temp tables, session settings, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let me first say it is best to use SqlClient in .NET applications for SQL Server data access. As a managed provider, SqlClient will be faster OLE DB or ODBC from managed .NET code, especially with large result sets.

It is expected to see the login and logout events in a SQL Trace, indicating the client has opened and closed a SQL connection. The RPC completed for `sp_reset_connection` indicates reuse of a pooled connection, resetting the session to the same state of a new physical connection (except isolation level).

**Note that SQL Trace doesn't show the network interactions when connection pooling is used**. Consider the open late, close early pattern used by many applications:

- open connection
- execute query
- close connection

The overhead of establishing the network connection and authentication is incurred only during the initial connection with connection pooling. A connection close only returns the connection to the pool and a subsequent open only retrieves an unused connection from the pool. Both are strictly client-side and do not send a network request to SQL Server. It is only when a query is executed on the pooled connection that a request is sent to SQL Server. This single request results in the following trace events:

- logout
- rpc completed for sp_reset_connection
- login
- rpc or batch completed for the application query

Because this occurs as a single request, there are no additional expensive network calls with connection pooling.